# Invertendo duas variáveis sem utilizar uma temporária

Tags: python

Como eu posso inverter o valor de `a` para `b` e `b` para `a` sem usar outra variável?
Por exemplo, `a` que vale `1` passa a valer `b` que vale `3` e `b` passa a valer `a` que valia `1`.

```
#antes de inverter
a = 1
b = 3

#depois de inverter
a = 3
b = 1
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Para fins práticos, prefira a atribuição múltipla, citada [nesta resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/395367/5878).

Por curiosidade:

Quando as variáveis forem inteiros, você pode inverter também com operações matemáticas de adição e subtração:

```
>>> a = 1
>>> b = 3

>>> a = a + b
>>> b = a - b
>>> a = a - b

>>> print('a =', a, 'b =', b)
a = 3 b = 1
```

Ou utilizando o operador XOR:

```
>>> a = 1
>>> b = 3

>>> a ^= b
>>> b ^= a
>>> a ^= b

>>> print('a =', a, 'b =', b)
a = 3 b = 1
```

Comment: Bela resposta Anderson! Nem havia pensado nestas maneiras, mas para fins de desempenho, teria alguma diferença entre adição e subtração; operação XOR; ou Atribuição dinâmica ou seria apenas várias maneiras de fazer a mesma operação?

Comment: @LuizAugusto No geral, isso seria micro otimização e, principalmente em Python, não precisaríamos nos preocupar com isso, mas sim, há diferenças. Pelo que analisei agora, a atribuição múltipla tende a ser a mais eficiente, mas foram testes rasos que não poderíamos confiar cegamente.

Answer (score 9):

Tente [Atribuição Múltipla](http://excript.com/python/atribuicao-multipla-python.html)

```
a=1
b=3

print("a=",a, "b=", b) 
a,b = b,a #Invertendo as variáveis sem uma variável auxiliar
print("a=",a, "b=", b)
```

Exemplo  acima é bem básico, mas funcional para o que você deseja.

Comment: Abri a pergunta [Atribuição múltipla no Python utiliza tuplas?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/395398/5878) para discutir o funcionamento interno por trás dessa atribuição múltipla.

Comment: Isso faz o que eu quero, mas se não me engano a tupla que vai ser desempacotada criará uma nova variável

Comment: @Nium Faz exatamente o que você precisa, tem mais detalhes no link do primeiro comentário.