# Gostaria de saber como faço para obter o valor da quantidade de comutações em uma ordenação de uma lista. sem usar sorted()

Tags: python

```
s = [2, 4, 3, 1, 6, 7, 5, 8]

for i in range(len(s)):

    for j in range(i+1,len(s)):
        if s[i] > s[j]:
            aux = s[i]
            s[i] = s[j]
            s[j] = aux
            
print(s)
```

Comment: Por favor, de mais detalhes sobre a sua dúvida. Também é bom utilizar a tag da linguagem que você está usando.

Comment: Veja esses dois links sobre como melhorar sua pergunta: https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/8089/guia-de-sobreviv%c3%aancia-do-sopt-vers%c3%a3o-curta?cb=1 e https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/8388/que-erro-eu-cometi-fazendo-minha-pergunta?cb=1 . Melhorando a pergunta, fica mais fácil para as pessoas te ajudarem.

Answer (score 1):

É só criar uma variável para contar, e incrementá-la quando tiver uma troca:

```
s = [2, 4, 3, 1, 6, 7, 5, 8]
cont = 0
for i in range(len(s)):
    for j in range(i+1,len(s)):
        if s[i] > s[j]:
            s[i], s[j] = s[j], s[i]
            cont += 1 # incrementa o contador
            
print(s) # [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
print(cont) # 6
```

A [outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/469619/112052) sugeriu criar uma função para fazer a troca e contabilização da mesma, mas para um caso simples como esse eu acho exagero. Incrementar o contador no próprio local onde a troca é feita me parece o suficiente.

Repare também que a troca pode ser feita com [atribuição múltipla](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/395367/112052), sem a necessidade de uma variável auxiliar.

Answer (score 0):

É so criar um contador que será contabilizado somente na hora que houver a troca, me parece que a linguagem é python

---

Sempre que houver uma troca ela é feita e retorna 1 caso contrário retorna 0

```
def troca(vetor,i,j):
   if vetor[i] > vetor[j]:
        aux = vetor[i]
        vetor[i] = vetor[j]
        vetor[j] = aux
        return 1
   return 0
```

---

Vetor a ser  ordenado
`vetor = [2, 4, 3, 1, 6, 7, 5, 8]`

Variavel de Controle `qtd = 0`

---

Percorre o vetor e tenta fazer uma troca ( so contabiliza caso a troca tenha ocorrido)

```
for i in range(len(vetor)):
    for j in range(i+1,len(vetor)):
      qtd = qtd + troca(vetor,i,j)
```

---

Confere a qunatidade de trocas ocorridas

```
print(qtd)
```

A sacada é criar a flag de controle e sempre que ocorrer a troca incrementá-la